# Copying to nested structures in C

Tags: c, syntax, copy, structure

I am trying to copy a structure x into another structure y that has x nested.

For example:

```
#define DATASIZE 128

typedef struct {
        char data[DATASIZE];    
} x_TYPE;


typedef struct {
    int               number;  
    x_TYPE            nested_x;     
    enum boolean      error;     
} y_TYPE;

/* ---- Values for the type field in xy_union ---- */
#define TYPE_IS_X 0;
#define TYPE_IS_Y 1;

typedef struct {
    union {                       /* structure containing x_object */
           x_TYPE      x_object; /*        or y_object as a union */
           y_TYPE      y_object;
    } u;
int type;            /*One of: TYPE_IS_X, TYPE_IS_Y */

} XY_TYPE;
```

This is how I currently copy:

```
copyXY(XY_TYPE *xx)
{
   XY_TYPE *yy; /* assume this is allocated already */


    yy->u.y_object.nested_x = *xx; /* ERROR LINE */


   return 0;
}
```

I get a compiler error of: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘x_TYPE’ from type ‘XY_TYPE’.

Please let me know if anyone knows why this occurs.

Comment: I fail to understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: The way you keep using "x" all over the place is confusing.

Comment: Your pseudo-code is **horrible** (for example, there's no type `x` defined; there's an `x_TYPE` but is that the same? Also `y_object` , which I assume is of type `y_TYPE` and not `y` doesn't contain an `x_object`). If you provided us with *actual* code that demonstrates the error you think you shouldn't be getting we may be able to help.

Comment: I updated the code. I am sorry this is the actual code. I am trying to figure out how to copy into y_object.nested_x

Comment: "I am trying to copy a structure x into another structure y that has x nested." - Apparently not: You're trying to copy a structure XY into another structure y that has x nested. The error says that x is not XY. What do you not understand here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
XY_TYPE *yy; /* assume this is allocated already */

void copyXIntoYY(XY_TYPE *xx)
{
    yy->u.y_object.nested_x = xx->u.x_object;
}
```

It isn't clear from the question what you are trying to do.